# jQuery qTip - Trigger before create

Tags: jquery, events, qtip

i try to trigger `someFunction()` before the qtip is created

```
$('.selector').qtip({
   content: {
      text: someFunction(this.id) }
});
```

This code works but i think this is a dirty solution. Is there maybe a `start: event` like in the most jquery plugins (for example draggable)? I found nothing about this it in the documentation.

**EDIT**: Ok, this code wont work. He trigger the function on pageload and not onhover.

**UPDATE**:

```
function someFunction(someId)
{
    // some code ...
    var searchResult = ' ... some results from the search -> from '+someId+' ... ';
    return searchResult;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Callback option `beforeShow :` , it's a better way to do this.

[**Reference here.**](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/api/#beforeShow)

Remove brackets from `someFunction` as well.

```
$('.selector').qtip({
    api : {
        beforeShow : function (someId)
        {
            // some code ...
            var searchResult = ' ... some results from the search -> from '+someId+' ... ';
            // place text in tooltip
        }
    }
});
```

**[Working Sample.](http://jsbin.com/aradaw/edit#preview)**

Comment: He wants to replace the text each onhover event, someFunction should replace it directly. `content: { text:` only write it once on page load

Comment: http://jsbin.com/olafop/edit#preview Can you test your code in this example please?

Comment: I "think" your solution is faster.

Comment: Using the provided qTip API for callbacks is faster, indeed. Thanks for considering it :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `someFunction`, not `someFunction()`. The latter calls the function and assigns the return value to `text` and then never calls the function again. By passing the function itself qTip will see the function and call it when necessary.

Comment: Can you give me a little example for "passing the function itself". Thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: In this case use an anonymous function: `text: function() { someFunction(self.id); }`. Before the call to the qtip function, add this: `var self = this;` - this ensures that you access the correct object inside the closure (which will have its own `this` bound to the global object)

Comment: I don't get it :/  Here is a little example. http://jsbin.com/olafop/edit#preview Can you edit the code? I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: I just noticed you are using the obsolete qtip1. You should really switch to qtip2; maybe v1 didn't support a callback function yet.

Answer (score 0):

In Qtip2, it has changed to jquery style ui events

```
$('.selector').qtip({
   events: {
      render: function(event, api) { }, // old onRender
      show: function(event, api) {}, // old beforeHide (return false or call event.preventDefault() to stop the show)
      hide: function(event, api) {} // old beforeHide (same as above)
   }
})
```